# Check if PYQT5 Widget is Visible in QGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to check if my widget is alredy open/visible before showing it (or before run this function). I need to check this because in my QGIS plugin it can happen that I call this function many times. I tried `isVisible()` but this code returns always false. How to do this check?

```
def run(self):
  self.dlg = Dialog()
  if self.dlg.isVisible():
    print("is visible")
    pass
  else:
    print("is not visible")
    self.dlg.show()

  # Run the dialog event loop
  result = self.dlg.exec_()

  # See if OK was pressed
  if result:
    #Do something
```

Comment: You can do this in several ways: Make the dialog modal so everything else is blocked from the QGIS GUI (even your plugin buttons, preventing opening multiple instances of your Dialog), or, even better, move your `self.dlg = Dialog()` line to the initGui() so you don't create new dialogs every time you call the `run()` method.

Comment: @Germán Carrillo commented while I was writing my answer. At least we seem to be on the same page :-)

Comment: Thank you both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you are creating a new instance of your dialog class every time the `run()` method is called. The `isVisible()` method is always returning false because you are calling it on the new instance of your dialog before you ever call `show()` on that object.

Why don't you declare self.dlg as an instance variable in the `__init__()` method.

For example:

```
class MyPlugin:

    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface
        self.dlg = Dialog()
```

Then in your run() method:

```
def run(self):
    if not self.dlg.isVisible():
        self.dlg.show()
```